# Why is a normal subgroup containing $\Phi (G)$ with a nilpotent factor group nilpotent?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

At page (28) of chapter I of the book *Finite Group Theory* by **I.Martin.Issacs**, one finds:

> Let $G$ be a finite group, with Frattini subgroup $\Phi$. If $\Phi \subseteq N \vartriangleleft G$, and if $N/ \Phi$ is nilpotent, then $N$ is nilpotent.

I know that this is in fact a generalisation of two preceding exercises, but I could not prove it: I have tried to construct a central series of $N$ from that of $N/ \Phi$, but failed to do so. I also tried in the direction of showing that maximal subgroups of $N$ are normal in $N$, but thus far found nothing interesting. As this is a generalisation of one exercise which deploits of the Frattini arguments, I wanted to avail myself of that argument as well, while finding nothing critical either. Therefore I post here for some help.
Sincere thanks.

Comment: Can you prove/use that the Frattini subgroup of a *finite* group is nilpotent?

Comment: Yes, that has already been proven.

Comment: I mean it has been proven by previous exercises...

Comment: This is Problem 1D.15 from Isaacs FGT.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We know that a finite group $\,G\,$ is nilpotent iff all its Sylow $\,p$-subgroups are normal, so this is what we're going to try to prove for $\,N\,$, so let $\,P\,$ be any Sylow $\,p$-subgroup of $\,N\,$ .

Putting $\,\Phi(G):=\Phi\,$ for simplicity, define $\,K:=P\Phi\leq N\,$ . Then $\,K/\Phi\,$ is a Sylow $\,p$-subgroup of $\,N/\Phi\,$ and since the last group is nilpotent then $\,K/\Phi\,\operatorname{char}\,N/\Phi\triangleleft G/\Phi\Longleftrightarrow K\triangleleft G\,$ (Remember that a finite group is nilpotent iff all its Sylow subgroups are normal, and in fact, characteristic).

Now use Frattini's Argument: $$G=N_G(P)K=N_G(P)\Phi\Longrightarrow G=N_G(P)\Longleftrightarrow P\triangleleft G\Longrightarrow P\triangleleft N$$

and were done.

Comment: Thanks very much: I did not come across the part that $K/ \Phi$ is a Sylow subgroup, thus is normal. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: By the way, the point you referred to in your comment is not used here. Perhaps you wanted to apply it somehow?

Comment: Yes, I know. I wrote below my original comment about this (that this seemed hopeless) but somehow the comment never showed up.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another proof.

Without loss of generality we may assume that $\Phi(G)\varsubsetneq N$, otherwise the result would be a direct consequence of Problem 1D.14. Pick a maximal subgroup $K\subseteq N$ such that $\Phi(G)\subseteq K$. Put $\bar K=K/\Phi(G)$ and $\bar N=N/\Phi(G)$. By Problem 1D.6, $\bar K\triangleleft \bar N$ and $p=|\bar N:\bar K|$ is prime. Therefore, $K\triangleleft N$ and $|N:K|=p$ is prime. In particular, $N/K$ is cyclic, hence abelian. Moreover, since $\bar K\subseteq\bar N$ is nilpotent, by induction on $|N|$ we may assume that $K$ is nilpotent. Given that $K\subseteq N$ will extend any central series for $K$ to a central series for $N$, the induction step immediately follows.